# How to inject all classes where the derived interface inherits another interface of a specific type? C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a series of classes where their interfaces inherit from a base interface.  I want to try and DI them all in one go.

```
public interface ICrud<T> { }

public interface ITestService : ICrud<Test> { }

public interface IAnotherService : ICrud<Another> { }

public class TestService : ITestService { }

public class AnotherService : IAnotherService { }
```

I originally tried injecting all services within the assembly, but that proved dangerous and caused issues when trying to inject specific instances.

```
    public static void AddAssemblyServices(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
    {
        var serviceTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Any());

        foreach (var serviceType in serviceTypes)
        {
            var implementedInterfaces = serviceType.GetInterfaces();
            foreach (var interfaceType in implementedInterfaces)
            {
                services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(interfaceType, serviceType, ServiceLifetime.Transient));
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried the following, but it hasn't returned any results

```
    public static void AddCrudServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(ICrud<>).Assembly;
        var serviceTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICrud<>)));

        AddAssemblyServices(services, serviceTypes);
    }
```

Comment: You might need a recursive test for the interfaces of the concrete class, since the interface you are looking for are base types of the interfaces of the concrete classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the interface is a constructed generic type and it's generic type definition matches the searched one:

```cs
var serviceTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(t => t is { IsClass: true, IsAbstract: false } 
         // here:
         && t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsConstructedGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICrud<>)))
    .ToList();
```